# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3306, 67, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to train a neural network on Semantic Role Labeling task (text classification task). The dataset consist of sentences on which the neural network has to be trained to predict a class for each word. Apart from using the embedding matrix, I am also using other features (meta_data_features). The number of classes in Y_train are 61. The number 3306 represents the number of sentences in my dataset (size of my dataset). MAX_LEN = 67. The code for the architecture is:

```
    embedding_layer = Embedding(67,
                                300,                                                                                                   
                                embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix),                                                         
                                input_length=MAX_LEN,
                                trainable=False)

    sentence_input = Input(shape=(67,), dtype='int32')
    meta_input = Input(shape=(67,), name='meta_input')

    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)

    x_1 = (SimpleRNN(256))(embedded_sequences) 

    x = concatenate([x_1, meta_input], axis=1)

    x = Dropout(0.3)(x)          

    x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)

    predictions = Dense(61, activation='softmax')(x)

    model = Model([sentence_input,meta_input], predictions)

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                    optimizer='adam',
                     metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])    

    print(model.summary())
```

The snapshot of model summary is:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 67)           0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 67, 300)      1176000     input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
simple_rnn_1 (SimpleRNN)        (None, 256)          142592      embedding_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
meta_input (InputLayer)         (None, 67)           0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 323)          0           simple_rnn_1[0][0]
                                                                 meta_input[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 323)          0           concatenate_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 32)           10368       dropout_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 61)           2013        dense_1[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,330,973
Trainable params: 154,973
Non-trainable params: 1,176,000
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The function call is:

```
simple_RNN_model_trainable.fit([padded_sentences, meta_data_features], padded_verbs,batch_size=32,epochs=1)
```

X_train constitutes **[padded_sentences, meta_data_features]** and Y_train is **padded_verbs**. Their shapes are:

padded_sentences - (3306, 67)

meta_data_features - (3306, 67)

padded_verbs - (3306, 67, 1)

When I try to fit the model, I get the error, "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (3306, 67, 1)"

It would be great if somebody can help me in resolving the error. Thanks!

Comment: What is the shape of the data after dense_1 layer? Can you Verify it?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? According to the error message, I believe it should be (3306,67,1). How to verify it?